# ANTLR G4 grammer for math expression

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

I am new to grammar and have written grammar for parsing math expression for [asciiMath](http://asciimath.org/) using ANTLR as below.

```
expression
    : expression BINARY_OPERATOR expression
    | UNARY_OPERATOR(expression)
    | LEFT_PARAM expression RIGHT_PARAM
    | VARIABLE
    | NUMBER
    ;

LEFT_PARAM
    : '(';

RIGHT_PARAM
    : ')';

VARIABLE
    : [A-Z]+
    | [a-z]+;

NUMBER
    : [0-9]+;

UNARY_OPERATOR
    : '-'
    | 'sqrt';

BINARY_OPERATOR
    : '+'
    | '-'
    | '*'
    | '/'
    | '^';
```

The problem is its not able to recogonize expression such as
**sqrt(a)**
The problem I guess for this is becoz `[a-z]+` is matching **sqrt** its treated as variable not unary operator, so I changed rule to `[a-z]` and it works but i guess it would not be able to recognize ab+cd as **ab** is more that one char.

Similarly for **a-b** its not recognizing because **-** is present in both unary and binary operator. If I remove from unary it works fine.
So this is happening due to ambiguity in the grammar I guess, can someone suggest how to remove the ambiguity?

Comment: I learned this recently: a sequence can only match one token, and when there are multiple possible matches, the longest one wins, then the one defined first. You might try moving the variable rule to the bottom

Comment: (I've seen *parenthesis* abbrev. to *paren* and find that less distracting than *PARAM*. (Not sure about `becoz` - I try not to irritate my spelling checker.))

Comment: (With parser tools I used, rules encountered earlier on took precedence over those specified further down. Try listing higher precedence (here: unary) or special (here *keyword* (`sqrt`)) cases first.)